# How can I have different product name for Device and Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

For example I want my project to build a target named "mylib_ios.a" for device and "mylib_sim.a" for simulator.

Edit: I want it change automatically when I build for simulator or device. Do I need a xconfig file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the target mylib_ios.a under TARGETS in Xcode and then select Duplicate.
2. Select the "my_lib_ios.a copy" under TARGETS.  Under Build Settings, search for "product name", rename it to mylib_sim.a
3. You can also rename the target by click on it once again.

Comment: Thanks but I want it change automatically.